# Kafka consumer group merge?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 4 topics:

```
topicA
topicB
topicC
topicD
```

I have 2 groups:

```
groupA
groupB
```

groupA is currently used against topicA and topicB

groupB is currently used against topicC and topicD

Is it possible to create a new consumer group that copies the topic partition offset commits of groupA for topicA and topicB and of groupB for topicC and topicD?

Can I do this for more than two groups at a time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to merge consumer groups and their current offset position in their topic partitions.

To get a solution you can make use of the `kafka-consumer-groups` command line tool. To merge the Consumer Groups groupA and groupB, you can first [check the offsets](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag) of groupB and then set the same offsets for groupA.

Setting the offsets can also be done with the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
 --execute --reset-offsets \
 --group groupA\
 --topic topicC \
 --partition 0 \
 --to-offset <insert number from groupB>
```

More details on the tool can be found in Kafka documentation, section [Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group)